# Is there a way to save a chosen color as a public variable?

Tags: swiftui, color-picker, public-method

I am implementing a Color Picker into my app. It works as intended, but i need to save the color as a public variable to use it in the next `View`.

I have coded the following:

```
struct Upload: View {
    @State var selectedColor = Color.black
        
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center) {
            ColorPicker(
                "Pick a color", selection: $selectedColor
            ).frame(width: 150, height: 150)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

The only color-choosing method my app has been designed for is the eyedropper tool, so I am looking for a way to get the color the **eyedropper** tool chose and save it as a **public variable**.

Please keep in mind this is only the code for the Color Picker - there is code around it, such as Stacks above and a `NavigationLink` Button below.

Comment: Are you familiar with Model (ObservableObject)? It would be best if you learn data dependancies in SwiftUI

Comment: You can’t save “Color” only UIColor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `onChange(of:)` to assign to a public variable when `selectedColor` is changed.

Add this to your view:

```swift
.onChange(of: selectedColor) { newValue in
    publicVariableColor = newValue
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are actually chosing and saving it. But to make it public, you need to do either of these two. You need to change `@State var selectedColor = Color.black` to `@AppStorage("selectedColor") var selectedColor = Color.black`. In the next view copy paste this code. Now the color will be saved to your apps data(Even if you re-open the app it doesn't go away.) and all views can use it(When you add the `@AppStorage("selectedColor") var selectedColor = Color.black` code).

If else like you don't want to save the color and only conected views will use it(I mean there is a `NavigationLink` to another view) use `@Bindning`. Here is how to use it.

```
struct download: View{
   @Bindning var selectedColor: Color
   var body: some View{
       selctedColor
   }
}
```

And here is how to use it in a NavigationLink:

```
NavigationLink("Download", destination: download(selectedColor: $selectedColor))
```

I hope this helped.